# How to remove that awful "Columns..." thing

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm using columntoggle mode because the output style is what I need/like. The system adds that row/button with "Columns..." (presumably so that you can pick which columns at run-time...which doesn't seem to work on my droid anyway.  I just want to remove it.

Comment: I found that css fragment elsewhere and it simply doens't work (for me at least).  The "Columns..." button still appears.  That seems to straightforward/obvious, but it doesn't hide t.

Comment: You can CSS the button away like suggested below, but of course, this only hides the button - it's still there, still being generated and still consuming memory. I filed a feature request for a table widget option `data-use-toggle-btn` and edited the widget in JQM to not generate a button. Works nice, so if you don't mind hacking the widget and adding it as an `extension.js` after JQM.js, then I can provide the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a demo:  **http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/28tNw/**

Basically you can just add the following CSS to hide the button:

```
.ui-table-columntoggle-btn {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: UPDATE: I originally had that css fragment in HEAD.  I moved it closer to where the html is and it works perfectly now. Very exciting. Not sure why...

Comment: it has to come after the inclusion of the jQM CSS files that originally define .ui-table-columntoggle-btn class in order to override it.